# Chrome Extension: How to run Javascript on page load (without popup open)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that does word substitutions on pages. Currently I have a popup that opens when I click on a browser action which lets the user control whether or not to perform the substitutions. I also have a background script running that sends a message to content scripts when a page refresh happens using a chrome.tabs.onUpdated event handler.

My problem is that when I refresh the page no substitutions are made unless the popup is open (which is only possible when I have the inspect elements panel open on the popup, because otherwise the popup closes when I refresh).

Has anybody had experience with this behavior before? What additional instrumentation should I add to diagnose the problem? Is there a different extension architecture/code arrangement I should be using?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use localStorage on a given page you can probably store whether or not to substitute words. I think refreshing a page is similar to opening a new tab, so your script gets reinjected/reloaded rather than staying open and receiving an onupdate message.

Comment: I've moved my comment to the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use localStorage on a given page you can probably store whether or not to substitute words. I think refreshing a page is similar to opening a new tab, so your script gets reinjected/reloaded rather than staying open and receiving an onupdate message.